# R allow reference classes to be member of reference class

Tags: r, reference-class

I'm trying to make "class1" an element of "class2". But when "class1" has an `initialize()` function, I get the following error:

```
class1 <-
  setRefClass(
    'class1',
    fields = list(attribute1 = 'character'),
    methods = list(
    initialize = function(a){
      attribute1 <<- a
    }
   )
  )

class2 <- 
  setRefClass(
    'class2',
    fields = list(attribute2 = 'class1')
  )
```

> Error in .Object$initialize(...) : 
>    argument "a" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 0):

Give the `initialize` method a default value:

```
class1 <-
  setRefClass(
    'class1',
    fields = list(attribute1 = 'character'),
    methods = list(
      initialize = function(a = NA_character_){
        attribute1 <<- a
      }
    )
  )

class2 <- 
  setRefClass(
    'class2',
    fields = list(attribute2 = 'class1')
  )
test <- class2()
> test
Reference class object of class "class2"
Field "attribute2":
  Reference class object of class "class1"
Field "attribute1":
  [1] NA
```